# how to test a method with more than one optional output?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
def game
  case rand(2)
  when 0
    "One"
  when 1
    "Two"
  end
end
```

Now I want to test it, so I wrote the following test:

```
require_relative 'random.rb'
require 'test/unit'

class StringTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def test_respond
    assert_equal("One" || "Two", game)
  end

end
```

But, the test only sees `"One"`, `"Two"` isn't seen. How I can fix it? Should I use something other than `||`? Or another function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"One" || "Two"
```

expression is always evaluated to `'One'`, because `"One"` is `truthy` value, so it never reaches to `"Two"` part.

You can go with

```
class StringTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_respond
    assert %w(One Two).include?(game)
  end
end
```